# Math.round not doing anything on my webpage

Tags: javascript

This is my page:
http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/3kc058darzus1uu/pythagoras_questions.html

And it's supposed to be a revision site for some students I'm tutoring, but I'm having some trouble getting a number to round to 2 dp and I'm not sure why. I've written on lines 99 to 107:

```
function answers() {
    c = Math.sqrt(a*a+b*b)
    console.log(c)
    Math.round(c*100)/100
    console.log(c)
    var el = document.getElementById("c")
    el.innerHTML="$"+c+"$"
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, el])
}
```

but for some reason it skips the Math.round() function. Here's a sample output from the console:

```
46.32493928760188
46.32493928760188
```

I just don't understand why it isn't rounding, what am I doing wrong? Strangely typing

```
Math.round(c*100)/100
```

directly into the console gives: `46.32`.

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot showing the problem (the number not being rounded and the console showing the output]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign the result of `Math.round` to a variable, e.g.

```
c = Math.round(c*100)/100;
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to assign the result (returned value) of `Math.round(c * 100) / 100` to the variable `c` again.

**And always use a semicolon to separate your JavaScript statements so that you won't have an error when two statements get on the same line (f.e. when you minify the js).**

```
function answers() {
    var c = Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b);
    c = Math.round(c * 100) / 100;
    var el = document.getElementById("c");
    el.innerHTML = "$" + c + "$";
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, el]);
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah, thanks everyone, that was a noobish mistake. I assumed Math.round would round it, but yes, of course, it returns the rounded value. How silly I am. In my defence it's exam time for me at uni and I'm distracted. I don't really use semicolons, I'm not very used to it and it seems to work well enough without.

Comment: Don't forget to mark one of the answers as correct. I recommend Genti Saliu's answer, since it came in first (by a few seconds). Several of us answered more-or-less simultaneously; I've upvoted the other two, since we can't all get points for a correct answer.

Comment: @JoeDeRose people are always commenting this on my questions. Is it only me that gets the "Wait x more minutes before accepting an answer"?

Comment: @captainjamie, it's just just you. I hope the reminder didn't offend -- it's just that so many people forget. If you want to forestall that reminder on future questions, it would probably work to upvote the answer you intend to accept, and add a comment saying you plan to mark it as correct when the timeout on accepting answers is finished.

Answer (score 4):

You need:

```
c = Math.round(c*100)/100;
```

As it is, your function doesn't update `c`, nor write its result to any variable.

Answer (score 0):

mkay why make multiple set's

when u can just

```
function answers() {
    c = Math.round(Math.sqrt(a*a+b*b)*100)/100
    console.log(c)
    var el = document.getElementById("c")
    el.innerHTML="$"+c+"$"
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, el])
}
```

Edit:

another alternative

if the number is already a float is the .toFixed() option

```
function answers() {
    c = Math.sqrt(a*a+b*b).toFixed(2)
    console.log(c)
    var el = document.getElementById("c")
    el.innerHTML="$"+c+"$"
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, el])
}
```

Comment: `Math.round(c)`  
`42`  
`Math.round(c*100)/100`  
`41.87` i.e. it rounds it to 2 dp not 0 dp

Comment: hmm thats odd i see it the same though gonna js fiddle

Comment: edited you really shouldnt do multi sets for the same thing unless your doing other code in between besides a console.log()

Comment: added another option (46.32493928760188).toFixed(2) === 46.32